# Is the Vāmakeśvara Taṃtra available with English Translation or Sanskrit Text?

Tags: shiva, translation-request, tantra

The Vāmakeśvara Taṃtra text with its sanskrit text or English translation or both, Is it available online or offline?

Comment: Have you looked here? - http://www.mlbd.com/

Comment: It does not contain

Comment: @Student I have scanned copy of the book. If you want it, just send me mail to my id in profile description.

Answer (score 5):

The Kulachudamani Tantra and Vāmakeśvara Taṃtra with commentary of Jayaratha was translated into English by Louise M Finn. Unfortunately, this book is not available online or offline.

[image]

I have got scanned copy of this book and i didn't post this book to archive.org or other site as i'm not sure of copyright status of this book.

Comment: this book is available on archive, but it doesn't contain the Sanskrit text. Could you please help, where I can find the Sanskrit text. I am not able to find it online.

Answer (score 3):

There are two books which are considered as part of Vamakeshwara. Some believe they are separate text but they are closely related to each other. One is sanskrit and another book is available with moola sanskrit and hindi commentary.

[Yogini Hridaya](https://www.scribd.com/document/266454681/Yogini-Hridaya-Vraj-Vallabha-Rare-Book)

[Nityashodashikarnava with Setu bandha](https://www.scribd.com/document/13883204/Nityashodashikarnava-With-Setubandha-Transliteration)

Comment: So Yogini Hridaya is also part of VT..I thought it was a separate Text..I have the book Kularnava Tantra where the commentator frequently cites in this fashion-From Vamakeswara Vachana as found in Nityoshodashikarnava..

Comment: majority believe that these two are part of VT ... you can go through both to understand better.